# How to save image in local storage using spring mvc and how upload image through postman?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am getting this error:

> the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

when I upload an image through postman like this: I have saveImage as url, in header I have content/type and multipart/form-data and choossed raw and uploaded an image.

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveImage",
 method = RequestMethod.POST, 
consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")


    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<GenericResponseVO<? extends IServiceVO>> getImage(
            @RequestBody(required = false) GenericRequestVO<ImageCriteriaVO> imageCriteriaVO,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) {
            return  requestHandlerInvoker.callHandler(
                HandlerName.SAVE_IMAGE_HANDLER,request,response,imageCriteriaVO);
    }
```

This my handler:

```
public GenericResponseVO<? extends IServiceVO> handleRequest(
            UserContext userCtx, HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse,
            GenericRequestVO<? extends IServiceVO> requestVO)
            throws O2Exception {
        GenericResponseVO<ImageResultVO> imageVO = new GenericResponseVO<ImageResultVO>();
        ImageResultVO imageResultVO = (ImageResultVO) serviceInvoker
            .callService(ServiceName.IMAGE_SERVICE, userCtx,requestVO.getBody());
        imageVO.setBody(imageResultVO);
        imageVO.getHeader().setStatus(new Status(Status.SUCCESS, "Token"));         
        return imageVO;
```

This my service:

```
public IServiceVO service(UserContext userCtx, IServiceVO inputVO)
            throws O2Exception {
        LOG.info(LoggingEvent.Image_INPROGRESS,"Inside get list of treasure hunt for corporate service");
        ImageCriteriaVO imageCriteriaVO = (ImageCriteriaVO) inputVO;
        System.out.println(imageCriteriaVO.getFile());
        ImageResultVO imageResultVO = new ImageResultVO();  
        CommonsMultipartFile file = null;           
            String fileName = null;
            if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
                    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                    BufferedOutputStream buffStream = 
                            new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("F:/" + fileName)));
                    buffStream.write(bytes);
                    buffStream.close();
                }catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }   

        return imageResultVO;
    }
```

This my criteria class:

```
public class ImageCriteriaVO implements IServiceVO{

    private byte[]  file;

    public byte[] getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(byte[] file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this answer may help

Remove `Content-Type` from header when you are trying to upload, Postman will do it automatically.

if you set `Content-Type: undefined`, Postman will automatically sets Content-Type to multipart/form-data and depending upon the media it will set boundary.

```
Mail user agents ignore content-disposition headers in the messages.
```

File name should be mentioned in filename parameter. Otherwise should be mentioned in  both filename and the name parameters5
[multipart/form-data with Angular JS](http://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs)